# How to change a text label from outside the 'Form.h'?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I'm a C++-CLI beginner and I have to get familiar with some simple things.
I made a form with 1 label and 1 button.
I want to change the text of the label by clicking on the button and calling some text via a void in another cpp class (changetext.cpp)

Structure:

**Form1.h //just a regular form code with 1 label and 1 button handler at the end**

```
#pragma once

namespace ms {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for Form1
/// </summary>
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

public:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~Form1()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
public: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
public: 
public: 

public:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

    #pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this->label1->AutoSize = true;
        this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(313, 140);
        this->label1->Name = L"label1";
        this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(35, 13);
        this->label1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->label1->Text = L"label1";
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(101, 117);
        this->button1->Name = L"button1";
        this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 58);
        this->button1->TabIndex = 1;
        this->button1->Text = L"button1";
        this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this,               &Form1::button1_Click);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(467, 262);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
        this->Name = L"Form1";
        this->Text = L"Form1";
        this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::Form1_Load);
        this->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->PerformLayout();

    }
    #pragma endregion
public: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {


         }
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

             changetext my = new changetext();
             my.changeText();

         }
};
    }
```

**ms.cpp (main) //just creates the form**

```
// ms.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"

using namespace ms;

[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
// Enabling Windows XP visual effects before any controls are created
Application::EnableVisualStyles();
Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

// Create the main window and run it
Application::Run(gcnew Form1());
return 0;
}
```

**changetext.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"

int number;

void changeText()
{
number = 5;
Form1.label1->Text=number;

}
```

I am making a little mistake somewhere and I guess it has to do with header files, I'm used to code in java so headerfiles are not my cup of tea yet.

Comment: "Form1" is a *type name*, not a variable that references the form object and could thus access its instance member named "label1".  Be sure to distinguish classes and objects, most any book about object oriented programming should be useful reading.

Comment: What is the right way to call the "label1" from "Form1.h" then?

Answer (score 1):

This is what to do:

Create getter in changetext.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"

int number = 5;

void getNumber()
{
return number;
}
```

Create header.h

```
#pragma once
void getNumber();
```

Include header.h and edit Form1.h

```
    #pragma once
#include header.h

namespace ms {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for Form1
/// </summary>
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

public:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~Form1()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
public: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
public: 
public: 

public:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

    #pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this->label1->AutoSize = true;
        this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(313, 140);
        this->label1->Name = L"label1";
        this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(35, 13);
        this->label1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->label1->Text = L"label1";
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(101, 117);
        this->button1->Name = L"button1";
        this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 58);
        this->button1->TabIndex = 1;
        this->button1->Text = L"button1";
        this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this,&Form1::button1_Click); 
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(467, 262);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
        this->Name = L"Form1";
        this->Text = L"Form1";
        this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::Form1_Load);
        this->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->PerformLayout();

    }
#pragma endregion
public: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {


         }
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

label1->Text=""+getNumber();

}
};
}
```